# Method reference to property setter

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

How could I get method reference to property setter without using kotlin-reflect?

Basically, if I'll write my code in java way it's super simple

```
fun setValue(i: Int) = Unit
val a: (Int) -> Unit = this::setValue
```

But for `var value: Int` I'm getting

```
var value = 1
val a: KMutableProperty0<Int> = this::value
```

Answer (score 5):

Slightly shorter: just use `this::value::set`

Comment: This is the best answer because it doesn't require reflection.

Answer (score 4):

`this::value` is a property reference. It returns a `KMutableProperty`. To get the setter you will need the `setter` field of `KMutableProperty`. So you will need this:

```
class C {
    var field: Int = 1
    fun getFieldSetter(): (Int) -> Unit{
        return this::field.setter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `this::value.setter` in order to get the setter reference.