# Kotlin - Double colon for getter and setter

Tags: java, kotlin

So... in Java we can call our getters and setters using the double colon operator, like this:

```java
myMethod(MyClass::getSomeVar, MyClass::setSomeVar);
```

In Kotlin we can do the same for the getter:

```kotlin
myFunction(MyClass::someVar, MyClass::?)
```

How would we do this for the setter in Kotlin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getters and Setters in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906607/getters-and-setters-in-kotlin)

Comment: I doubt there's a way to use the `::` syntax for that. Just use a lambda

Comment: The `::` is called a method reference. For properties you do `MyClass::p.setter` and `MyClass::p.getter`. This was already answered at [Method reference to property setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933370/method-reference-to-property-setter)

Comment: This question has already been asked.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598320/kotlin-method-reference-not-working

Comment: Oh wauw. That setter reference worked. Thanks!

Comment: Or just `MyClass::someVar::set`